# Simple modeling rules to get sensible UV mapping

Tags: modeling, uv, workflow

I'm learning blender and came upon this small problem when trying to uv-unwrap the small hinge below.

I'll start by telling how I made it, as it might help answer the question.
I simply took a cube made it flat, and used the knife-tool to cut it in two.
This made the shape on the right (squared out?), where the front and the back are one n-gon (as I see it). But this produces the uvmap at the bottom right?

I then removed the face and build up the front and back with tris and quads, and the unwrap ended up as expected.

[image: hinge and UV map]

So my question is, how do I ensure that I do not end up in the same situation again, when modeling? I don't want to go back and having to add tris and/or quads to get a sensible unwrapping.
Are there some rule of thumb to follow, to ensure a good unwrapping result.

Comment: Sorry for being late. Have you been using seams?

Answer (score 1):

If you try unwrap flat surface - the best method for this is <kbd>U</kbd> -> Project from view (Bounds).

[image]

It just copy real position of vertexes from current view to UV, without any distortions.